# Бизнес-логика, что это такое?

Tags: терминология, шаблоны-проектирования

> Шаблон MVC описывает простой способ построения структуры приложения,
>   целью которого является отделение **бизнес-логики** от
>   **пользовательского интерфейса**. В результате, приложение легче масштабируется, тестируется, сопровождается и конечно же реализуется.

[Источник](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/)

Не совсем ясно, что означает этот термин

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Бизнес-логика - это логика доменной модели - все, что в вашем приложении происходит в терминах предметной области.

Например, на SO - это все действия с пользователями, вопросами, ответами, плюсы, минусы и т.д.

Пример:

1. Если пользователь не набрал ZZZ репутации - отправить его правку на проверку другими участниками - это бизнес-логика, ей место в модели.
2. Перенаправить пользователя на страницу вопроса после его создания - не-бизнес логика, которой место в контроллере.
3. Скрыть кнопку "Оставить комментарий" если текущий пользователь не имеет право оставлять комментарии - особенности представление данных (флага из модели) - во view.

MVC позволяет выделить "не-бизнес" логику, связанную с пользовательским интерфейсом:

- вызовы методов модели по определенным действиям пользователя
- отображение/скрытие контролов
- подготовку данных к отправке на клиента.

... и поместить логику представления в отдельный кусок приложения - Controller.

тем самым оставив в модели "чистую" бизнес-логику, не привязанную к интерфейсу пользователя.

---

Стоит отметить, что ссылка в вопросе ведет на статью, иллюстрированную диаграммой Classic MVC. Реально в Web используется более современный вариант паттерна - MVC Model2 - и его производные. Его отличие - View не взаимодействует с моделью напрямую.

Взаимодействие в современном MVC выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оборот про "_И поместить ее в отдельный кусок приложения - Controller._" совсем не понятен. А еще не понятно как бизнес-логика связана с контролером

Comment: Я к тому, что процитированный мной кусок, по-логике содержит опечатку. Вместо _Controller_ должно быть _Model_. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev о, там предложения местами поменялись. исправил, спасибо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну да, "предметная область и ее логика" и "код, реализующий логику предметной области" - это две разные вещи. Но обычно под BL подразумевают именно часть приложения, в которой логика предметной области изложена в виде кода. А не просто какие-то абстрактные правила, которые существуют в голове у экспертов в предметной области.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я попытался привести конкретный пример в ответе. он недостаточно понятен? чем именно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov вам понятен и достаточен - кому-то другому - нет. :) Остальной текст и диаграмма там в качестве компенсации ошибки в статье на хабре.

Comment: @PavelMayorov переставил повыше, может быть стало понятнее

Comment: @PashaPash да, так лучше

Comment: *"Если пользователь не имеет права создавать комментарии - скрыть от него кнопку "оставить комментарий" - это **логика представления**, ей место **в контроллере**."* - э...

Comment: @PavelMayorov можете привести пример на логику представления чуть получше? с удовольствием заменю неоднозначный из ответа.

Comment: @PavelMayorov пример с "редиректнуть незалогиненного пользователя на страницу login" подойдет? :)

Comment: @PashaPash да, вполне подойдет. Кстати, прошлый вариант тоже можно оставить - только исправить местонахождение логики представления на представление :)

Comment: @PashaPash хотя нет, лучше не оставлять. Проверка наличия прав у пользователя вполне может быть и бизнес-логикой, особенно в кровавом энтерпрайзе.

Comment: @PavelMayorov меня просто напрягает перевод терминов presentation / ui / view как "представление". просто достаточно тяжело объяснить разницу между самой проверкой прав и ее проявлением в UI (вообще нельзя / не показать кнопку) :)

Comment: А, например, обработка ответа сервера при авторизации(например, если код 600 то вывести сообщение "учетка не активирована") - это бизнес логика? В тот же момент, если ответ 500 то вывести сообщение "ошибка сервера" - это бизнес логика?

Comment: @DuosDuo очень легко проверить. Представьте, что у вас есть полностью другой ui, например, мобильное приложение. Если в нем поведение будет другое - то это не бизнес логика. Показать сообщение - не бизнес логика. Проверить активацию учётки, залогировать для аудита попытку доступа - бизнес логика.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Продолжу с авторизацией:) 1. Проверка ответа авторизации, в общем - это бизнес логика. 2. При статусе авторизации = 200, сохранить cookie в локальный repository для дальнейшего использования - это бизнес логика. 3. При статусе авторизации = 200, открыть главный раздел приложения - это не бизнес логика. 4. При статусе авторизации = 500, показать окно с ошибкой - не безнес логика. Правильно ? Если не сложно, можете расписать почему тот или иной пункт является или не является бизнес логикой? Почему то сейчас, в конце, начинаю думать что п.1 это не совсем бизнес логика?..

Answer (score 17):

Бизнес-логика - то же самое что и логика предметной/доменной/прикладной области. Допустим, вы программируете софт для приюта животных и для детского приюта.

По бизнес-логике приюта для животных, предположим, котика, которого за неделю не забрали новые хозяева, надо усыпить. А до этого его надо кормить, поить и спать укладывать.

По бизнес-логике детского приюта - ребенка надо кормить, поить и спать укладывать. В него нельзя втыкать шприц со смертельной дозой морфия.

При этом все структуры данных, алгоритмы и т.д. - в двух программах практически одинаковы. Кроме вот этой маленькой детали.

"ЭТОТ один ИФЧИК решил СУДЬБУ КОТЕЙКИ", или, например "начинающий программист УБИЛ младенца ВЕКТОРОМ"

Если вы перепутаете бизнес-логику приюта для животных и детского приюта,  и усыпите ребенка, а котенку подарите куклу, вы, надеюсь, попадете в тюрячку, там вам все за ООП расскажут.

Не важно, бизнес это, расчет конфигурации молекул, приют или управление кораблем. Бизнес-логика - это та самая часть, которая в итоге должна работать правильно и надежно, та, результатов которой ждет заказчик (котенок, ребенок)

Если не отделять, допустим *интерфейс* от бизнес-логики, то вместо нажатия кнопки "отдать ребенка новым родителям" или "усыпить котенка", на двух аккуратных -  почти похожих -  пультах управления (интерфейсах) вы будете бегать туда-сюда, пытаясь понять, кого утопить, кого усыпить, кого отдать новым родителям и почему ничего не работает.

Вы не отделили интерфейс (панель управления для запуска котят на луну) от бизнес-логики и все запуталось.

Ну, я предупреждал.

Используете вы синглтоны, очереди, базы данных, флэт-файлы, микросервисы - не важно - важно, чтобы бизнес-логика работала правильно.

Под *правильно* подразумевается *корректность* результатов в *приемлемое* время. Все остальное ваших заказчиков не интересует. До тех пор, пока они не являются вашими владельцами.

Именно поэтому вы можете продавать очень плохой - с точки зрения программиста - софт клиентам, но с трудом сможете построить на нем надежную систему. Требования бизнес-логики может быть и выполняются, но поддерживать этот код *невозможно*

P.S. Маленький исторический экскурс.
Бизнес-логикой это называется потому, что в Нормальном Мире, во Внешней Империи, программирование в коммерции и корпорациях развивалось еще с 50х-60х годов: банки, страховые агентства, туроператоры, медицина.

Т.е. тебе платили за то, чтобы ты внедрил требования конкретного бизнеса

Хорошо, что это бизнес-логика, а не партийная логика, как в Северной Корее.

Comment: `ЭТОТ один ИФЧИК решил СУДЬБУ КОТЕЙКИ` - в итоге  ифчик - результат обычной логики. Не смотря на то, что строилось приложение для какого-либо бизнеса

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, этот "ифчик" относится к принципиально выделенному слою приложения. Его нельзя зафигачить _где угодно_.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev тем не менее, это поведение, в зависимости от некоего условия, чем и является, по своей сути, сама логика))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я понимаю, что вы хотите как-то защитить свою позицию, но вы должны понимать, что в software engineering  понятие `logic` означает не абстрактное слово и не математическое понятие логики, а "слой" или "область" кода. - в зависимости от архитектуры. Сущность. Сущность, которая работает с графикой не должна отправлять почту, сущность, которая работает с файлами, не должна рисовать html. Бизнес-логика - это алгоритм решения конкретной задачи - "повысить продажи", "предупредить о наводнении", "убить котенка", "выдать рецепт".

Comment: @strangeqargo да я уже давно это всё понял, что это и чему. что для IT это норма, что бизнес логика != логика )) Надо будет со спецами на этом языке говорить, но для себя лично у меня останется все так как есть.)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это само пройдет, если вам не повезет войти по колено в какой-нибудь энтерпрайз

Answer (score 9):

Это логика, которая рассматривает задачу в терминах реального мира, конкретного бизнеса. То есть это может быть прогрессивная шкала налогообложения, (именно описание того, как она формируется и что из этого получается), принципы формирования счетов, распределение коэффициентов зарплат сотрудников, но не порядок подключения файлов в движке, не подстройка балансировки нагрузки: это наши проблемы, а не бизнеса.

Comment: Простой пример: Покупатель (клиент) получает товар, а компания получает деньги - это бизнес-логика.
Под ней может лежать куча обращений к БД и всяческих расчётов - это уже собственно логика приложения.

Comment: вот это уже - понятно : мухи отдельно от котлет хм...

Answer (score 1):

К примеру у вас приложение справочник телефонных номеров. 
В зависимости от кода страны вы будете использовать то или иной формат отображения. В базе данных вы будете хранить без форматирования (для улучшения индексации и поиска). Так вот, вы можете вытащить номера прямо из базы и форматировать отображение телефонного номера в **View**. Но лучше всего создать слой **(бизнес слой)** который будет заниматься вытаскиванием из базы и форматированием (что и называется **бизнес логикой**), и передать в **View**. Нужно чётко понимать что **View** это представление, он показывает то что мы дадим, а не по своему.

Answer (score 0):

Читайте **бизнес-логика**, как просто **логика**. Всё.

А отделение её от `UI` - то и означает: что в представлении не должно всяких обращений к БД, выборок из неё, вспомогательных функций на N-строк, например хитроумная сортировка, фильтрация, структурирование данных; шифрование данных; проверка на правильность логина/пароля и прочих каких-либо сверх манипуляций с данными.

В представлении должно быть отображение конечного результата, который придет в ответ на запрос к управляющему классу, а всё манипулирование (как описано выше) данными (**логика**) - должно происходить в другом месте.

---

The end.

Comment: Увы, бизнес-логика - это именно **бизнес**-логика. В отличии от логики приложения (БД, инфраструктура, инфраструктурные сервисы, и прочее) бизнес-логика выражает (вы не поверите) то, как работает именно **бизнес** (а не ваше приложение). В этом слое все должно выражаться в терминах модели предметной области. Код на данном этапе вторичен.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Ну так вы бы ответ написали.

Comment: @VladD, хороший развернутый ответ потребует очень много буков. Прямо сейчас у меня столько буков нету =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev: Ну так сделайте хоть набросок и пообещайте дополнить новыми, как только поступят в ваше распоряжение.

Comment: а кто минусанул  ответ ?

Comment: @Geyan Можете убрать галку и почитать ответы PashaPash и DmitriySimushev (если он соизволит все же написать ответ) .... Они вам попытаются объяснить. Их бизнес логика != моя бизнес логика))

Comment: Алексей Шиманский  я не могу (как к примеру на toster) выбрать все ответы как лучшие , я уже ранее сказал Вам что ваш ответ меня устроил в комментарии ниже **читайте бизнес-логика, как просто логика ..... а отделение от UI то и означает, что в представлении не должно всяких обращений к БД, выборок, каких-то сверх манипуляций с данными и прочей лишней логики.. в представлении должно быть отображение конечного результата... а всё манипулирование данными (логика) должно происходить в другом месте –**

Comment: @Geyan, то, что ответ вас устроил, не делает его правильным. Отсюда и минусы (мой там тоже есть)

Comment: ваш ответ верный ? я не знаю кому верить

Comment: @Geyan дело в том, что логика != манипулиование данными. и бизнес логика != логика. Паттерн MVC отделяет логику представления от логики предметной области. Это его *суть*. А вы приняли ответ, в котором буквально сказано "логика она и есть логика, нечего в ней делить". Т.е. вас такой ответ устроил. Но это не делает его верным.

Comment: @Geyan верьте мне! и количеству голосов :)

Comment: PashaPash теперя по русскому и без хитроумных слов , о чём Вы мне написали ?

Comment: @Geyan бизнес логика - это не "вся логика". это если совсем коротко.

Comment: Бизнес-логика: пользователь онлайн игры потратил 100 рублей и получил 1000 игрового золота. Логика приложения: пользователь с id 123 завершил транзакцию перевода средств на счёт проекта. Проект посчитал по курсу, сколько это в игровом золоте, согласно данным из таблицы котировок. Данные в таблице статистики игрока обновились в сторону увеличения игрового счёта. - Последнее уже ближе к "просто логике" приложения.

Comment: без литра не разберёшся, я понял теперя

Comment: @Geyan https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0 в википедии посмотри дополнительно, узнаешь, кто где прав